# macOS Safari not playing Facebook videos in HD

Tags: macos, safari, video, facebook

I have uploaded a few videos to my personal Facebook page.

They are all 2720 x 1530, H.264, AAC

After the upload, if I try to play them in Safari the HD icon is disabled and I can't switch the HD on, so they would always play in SD. However, if I play the same video in Chrome, Firefox etc.. it plays normally in HD.

What is going on here?

Comment: Great first question! Welcome to Ask Different Jure!